# Printing calendar for specific year and month

Tags: c, calendar

I am trying to print out a calendar for a specific year and month but keep getting the same calendar for every month. I tried to also add a statement to see if the year is a leap year to add to the number of days but it made no difference. I am new to c.Please help with any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
    void print_month_calendar(int year, int month)
{
    int day;
    int daycode = ddaycode(year);
    int days_in_month[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

char *months[]=
            {
                    " ",
                    "\n\n\nJanuary",
                    "\n\n\nFebruary",
                    "\n\n\nMarch",
                    "\n\n\nApril",
                    "\n\n\nMay",
                    "\n\n\nJune",
                    "\n\n\nJuly",
                    "\n\n\nAugust",
                    "\n\n\nSeptember",
                    "\n\n\nOctober",
                    "\n\n\nNovember",
                    "\n\n\nDecember"
            };

    printf("%s", months[month]);
    printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

    if(( year%4==0 && year%100 !=0) || year%400==0)
        days_in_month[2] = 29;

    for (day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 5; day++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    //Print all the dates for the month
    for (day = 1; day <= days_in_month[month]; day++)
    {
        printf("%2d", day);

        if ((day + daycode) % 7 > 0)
            printf("   ");
        else
            printf("\n ");
    }
}

int ddaycode(int year)
{
    int daycode;
    int d1, d2, d3;

    d1 = (year - 1.)/ 4.0;
    d2 = (year - 1.)/ 100.;
    d3 = (year - 1.)/ 400.;
    daycode = (year + d1 - d2 + d3) %7;
    return daycode;
}
```

Comment: Your daycode computation doesn't take the month into account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the first weekday in the month. You can use `localtime` to go to specific date, use `mktime` to get `struct tm` data which contains weekday. In addition, you can use `strftime` to get the month name. Example:

```
void print_month_calendar(int year, int month)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    timeinfo->tm_year = year - 1900;
    timeinfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
    timeinfo->tm_mday = 1;
    mktime(timeinfo);

    //sunday is 1 ... saturday is 7
    int weekday = 1 + timeinfo->tm_wday;

    int days_in_month[] = { 0, 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        days_in_month[2]++;

    char monthname[30];
    strftime(monthname, sizeof(monthname), "%B", timeinfo);

    printf(" %s %d\n", monthname, year);
    printf(" Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n");

    int day = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        if (i < weekday)
        {
            printf("    ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%3d ", day);
            if (day == days_in_month[month])
                break;
            day++;
            if ((i % 7) == 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
    print_month_calendar(2016, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/aWoP08)

> ```
>  October 2016
>  Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
>                           1 
>   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
>   9  10  11  12  13  14  15 
>  16  17  18  19  20  21  22 
>  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 
>  30  31
> ```

Comment: Interesting: on my Mac, I get a calendar that looks like: `October` —
`Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa` —
                          `7` — (this 7 is right adjusted under `Sa`) —
  `8   9  10  11  12  13  14` —
 `15  16  17  18  19  20  21` —
 `22  23  24  25  26  27  28` —
 `29  30` — where the problems are that the first date printed is the 7th, and only days up to 30 are printed, not 31.  (I can sympathize with wanting to do away with Halloween, but…)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I had the wrong loop, it should be okay now!

Comment: What happened to 1st through 6th October?  This year (2016), the 1st of October falls on Saturday, and the 31st falls on Monday.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I need glasses. I fixed it so it should work for October 2016, I'll run more tests.

Comment: It works for November 2016 too, now, and February 2016.  Don't try September 1752 (but do try `cal 9 1752`).